# SlickGrid and Text Selection

Tags: slickgrid

In the [demos](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html) I have seen and in my own code, SlickGrid cells do not allow their text to be selected.  Is it possible to allow the user to select text from cells.  If so, how?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Set the `enableTextSelectionOnCells` option to true.

Comment: Thanks for writing SlickGrid, and for being on SO.  Almost afraid to upvote your answer as it runs counter to the theme of your gold badge :-)