# Slickgrid cell text selection does not work properly in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: slickgrid

I have set enableTextSelectionOnCells according to [SlickGrid and Text Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966390/slickgrid-and-text-selection?rq=1).

I am not really happy about it.

Cell text gets selected with a bad behaviour. Sometimes as soon as selection is done, the selection disappears. Only on rare occasions does it work.

Has anyone faced this issue?

I have tried this on Firefox and Chrome.

to reproduce:

1. `git clone git@github.com:mleibman/SlickGrid.git`
2. go to `examples` folder
3. edit the `example1-simple.html`
4. Add `enableTextSelectionOnCells: true` in options
5. Open `example1-simple.html` in FF/Chrome
6. Try selecting a cell value

FYI, I am running on Ubuntu if it should make any difference.

Comment: I am having the same issue on chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is already solved on [Github](https://github.com/ptraca/SlickGrid/commit/f85f023ec945e968d27f11151164d9e9881631a4). You just have to modify slick.gird.js. Around line number 2270, you just have to add " options.editable && ". Hope this help.

```
if (!currentEditor) {
    // if this click resulted in some cell child node getting focus,
    // don't steal it back - keyboard events will still bubble up
    // IE9+ seems to default DIVs to tabIndex=0 instead of -1, so check for cell clicks directly.
    if (options.editable && e.target != document.activeElement || $(e.target).hasClass("slick-cell")) {
      setFocus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had forgotten about this altogether after giving up a long time ago